# Periodic function of period $k$ that is continuous at $x_{0}$ must be continuous at $x_{0}+k$?

Tags: calculus, limits

I got this question:

Let $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a periodic function of period $k$ that is continuous at $x_0$, Must it be the case that $f$ is continuous at $x_0 + k$?

If so how do I prove it (by using the definition of limit) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f$ being continuous at $x_0$ so for $\epsilon>0$ there's $\delta>0$ s.t.
$$|f(x)-f(x_0)|<\epsilon$$
whenever $x:|x-x_0|<\delta$ but in this case we have $|x-x_0|<\delta\iff|(x+k)-(x_0+k)|
<\delta$
and then
$$|f(x)-f(x_0)|=|f(x+k)-f(x_0+k)|<\epsilon$$
hence $f$ is continuous at $x_0+k$.

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: Good work, Sami!